# Dynamic Rendered Cell filter on Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

On the material table library, I am trying to filter a field that is custom rendered. The official document does not have any example of custom column rendering plus filtering that column. I have tried to use the lookup function, but I am not successful.

Here is the official document: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering

Here is an implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table---create-dinamic-object-to-lookup-forked-9px53?file=/src/index.js

What would be my best option here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that the field `customFilterAndSearch` can help me on this one. For the ones who arrived here, to solve the problem I have made a quick search on my array:

```
  customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) => {
          return rowData.lived.find((place) => {
            return place?.name?.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
          });
        }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table---create-dinamic-object-to-lookup-forked-2ed1n?file=/src/index.js

let me know if you think I could improve this.